# Link each category to last post

Tags: categories

I would like that each category link to the last post of each category.

- category 1 ----> link to the last post of category 1
- category 2 ----> link to the last post of category 2
- category 3 ----> link to the last post of category 3

How can I do it?

Comment: **Where** do you want to have this? In a _hand-made_ category listing? In a category widget? For the URLs `http://example.com/category/my-cat/` etc? This is not enough information.

Comment: There is really no such thing as the "first" post in a category. The display order depends on the query parameters.

Comment: I want to have this in a menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `category_link` and replace the URL here. I have used the *newest* post in the following example, because *first* could also mean the *oldest* and that sounds … strange. :)

```
add_filter( 'category_link', 'wpse_96677_cat_link_to_first_post', 10, 2 );

function wpse_96677_cat_link_to_first_post( $url, $term_id )
{
    $term = get_term( $term_id, 'category' );

    // sub-terms only
    if ( ! isset ( $term->parent ) or 0 == $term->parent )
        return $url;

    $post = get_posts(
        array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'category'   => $term_id
        )
    );

    if ( ! $post )
        return $url;

    return get_permalink( $post[0]->ID );
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks... And If I want to link to a post only the second level of categories?

Comment: @Mike I made an update, the links are now changed for categories with parents only.